# Can't get "\a" to output a beep sound

Tags: c++

I'm on another person's Mac-book Pro and I'm trying to output the alarm sound in `C++` by outputting `"\a"` with `cout`. For some reason it's not making any sound when it outputs. Does anyone know why this could be happening? I'm using `Eclipse`.

Comment: `std::cout << '\a' << std::endl;` works fine for my Macbook Pro under Windows 7.

Comment: Did you check what they might've set their beep sound to? On my MacBook Pro it's a sonar ping. They might've set it to be silent.

Comment: In some systems it just won't work. For example my old desktop PC used to run a program (that I wrote myself) that beeps perfectly, and my current laptop just won't make any sounds. I've searched for it, and found nothing. No settings in windows, no settings in the BIOS or anything. (and YES, volume is on :)) But it would be a nice idea to look into BIOS settings or audio driver settings, if there is. That may help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse's shell likely isn't wired up to interpret the classic BELL character correctly.

I can confirm that the bell does operate on Terminal.app however.

Note that the bell character is not part of C++ - it is purely a side effect of the console/terminal in use.

Comment: Once I ran it on the terminal, the sound did indeed play. Thanks! Eclipse simply didn't interpret it apparently like you said.