# escape code Constants in C++

Tags: c++

My instructor gave us some sample code and she used a `\a1` `\a2` `\a3` `\a4` `\a5`
Can someone tell me what it is used for? I can't find it online or in my textbook?

```
cout<<"\n\t\a\a1----INSERT A NODE IN A BINARY TREE.\a\a";
cout<<"\n\t\a\a2----PRE-ORDER TRAVERSAL.\a\a";
cout<<"\n\t\a\a3----IN-ORDER TRAVERSAL.\a\a";
cout<<"\n\t\a\a4----POST-ORDER TRAVERSAL.\a\a";
cout<<"\n\t\a\a5----EXIT.\a\a";
cout<<"\n\t\a\aENTER CHOICE::\a\a";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727518/cant-get-a-to-output-a-beep-sound

Comment: The escape sequence is just `\a`. `\a1` is just bell, then the normal character `1`. So the numbers are not part of the escape sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\a` is "alert", or "bell". It's listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), for instance. Running this on a terminal with an actual audible bell (or even a visual one, where the whole screen flashes briefly) would surely be horrible. That's rather strange code to get from an instructor.

The sequence `\a1` is simply `\a` followed by the digit `1`, it's not a two-letter escape code.

Comment: okay thank you, i am confused and searching in the whole internet and book, i didn't get any answer... but i know \a is a alert beep.

Comment: The instructor wanted to really make sure you were paying attention.

Answer (score 4):

`\a` is alert, `\n` is newline, `\t` is tabulation. `1` is 1 :-)

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

- `\n` - line break
- `\t` - tabulation symbol
- `\a` - sound in the
  console

So `\a1` means `\a` sound and symbol `1`

Answer (score 1):

`\a` are the speaker bells usually...